# how to remove error in Spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

If user select Admin from Spinner dropdown menu this activity move to About.class and when user select Teacher from Spinner dropdown menu this activity moves to Student.class but errors occur. 
Errors come in these lines:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
```

Description Resource    Path    Location Type
    The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})   Home.java   /StudentRecord/src/edu/riphah/fun/StudentRecord line 40 Java Problem

Home.java code:

```
public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button Btn,Btn1;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        String delegate = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm aa"; 
        java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        textView2.setText("Time:"+DateFormat.format(delegate,noteTS));
        init();

        String[] sp1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Level);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sp1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String s=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                if(s.equals("Admin"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),About.class));
                if(s.equals("Teacher"))
                    startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),Student.class));

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });


    }
```

String code:

```
<string-array name="Level">
        <item>Admin</item>
        <item>Teacher</item>
        <item>Dean</item>
    </string-array>
```

XML code:

```
<Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
          android:entries="@array/Level" />
```

Comment: because of this error application does not running Description Resource Path Location Type
The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){}) Home.java /StudentRecord/src/edu/riphah/fun/StudentRecord line 40 Java Problem

Comment: Seem to be wrong import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are importing wrong class

Make sure you are importing

```
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

or change the line

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

to

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

**EDIT**
You should change

```
String s=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

to

```
String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: thanks :)when i import, android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener app run properly